# Average behavior of $\lambda (n)^2$ over natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f\in S_k(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ be  a cusp eigenfunction of all Hecke operators $T_nf=\lambda(n)f,$ then $f$ has the following Fourier expansion at the cusp $\infty$: $$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1}a(n)q^n\quad q:=e^{2\pi inz}$$
suppose the $f$  normalized ( $a(1) = 1.$) Then we have $$\lambda(n)=\frac{a(n)}{n^{\frac{k-1}{2}}}.$$
Can someone help me to prove the following  [asymptotic formula](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-08/S0002-9939-09-09855-4/S0002-9939-09-09855-4.pdf) : $$\sum_{n\le x}\lambda(n)^2=c.x+O(x^{3/5})\quad (*)$$

I think that we must start with 
$$\sum_{n\le x}\lambda(n)^2=\sum_{n\le x}\frac{a(n)^2}{n^{k-1}}=\frac{A(x)}{x^{k-1}}+(k-1)\int_1^x\frac{A(t)}{t^k}dt$$
where $A(x):=\sum_{n\le x}a(n)^2$ and then use [Rankin's paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/contributions-to-the-theory-of-ramanujans-function-n-and-similar-arithmetical-functions/99EDBBF0BB90BDF4CA68E1B033B7E742) to get $(*)$

Comment: [from $|a(n)| \le d(n) n^{(k-1)/2}$](http://mathoverflow.net/a/43951/84768)  you'll have $|\lambda(n)| \le d(n)$ and $\sum_{n < x} \lambda(n)^2 \le\sum_{n < x} d(n)^2 \sim \frac{6}{\zeta(2)} x (\ln x)^3$ (from $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n)^2 n^{-s} = \frac{\zeta(s)^4}{\zeta(2s)}$)

Comment: @user1952009, Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I meant $\frac{1}{3! \zeta(2)} x(\ln x)^3$. And the solution should be with  [the Rankin-Selberg convolution](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167931/functional-equation-and-conductor-for-a-rankin-selberg-convolution) so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n)|^2 n^{-s} = L(s,f \times \overline{f})$

Comment: @user1952009,I think so

Comment: We can't read Rankin's paper. And do you know how to prove the Rankin-Selberg convolution is meromorphic ? (I don't)

Comment: @user1952009, yes this is explained in [these notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/basic_rankin_selberg.pdf)

Comment: it shows that $h(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n)|^2 n^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|a(n)|^2}{n^{s+2k-1}} = \frac{(4\pi)^{s+2k-1}}{\Gamma(s+2k-1)} \langle f.E_s,\overline{f} \rangle$ [where $E_s$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analytic_Eisenstein_series#As_a_function_on_s) is analytic except a pole of order $1$ at $s=1$, and $\xi(2s)$ analytic on $Re(s)> 1/2$, hence $h(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$ of order $1$, and no other on $Re(s) > 1/2$, so you should get $\sum_{n < x} |\lambda(n)|^2 = c x + \mathcal{O}(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$

Comment: Thank you very much dear @user1952009,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have accessed to [Rankin's paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/contributions-to-the-theory-of-ramanujans-function-n-and-similar-arithmetical-functions/889C98A56757531D5B2E4CD59CF1D606) in which he proves that if $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}a(n)q^n\in S_{k}(N,\chi)$ is a modular form we have $$A(x):=\sum_{n\le x}|a(n)|^2=\alpha x^k+O(x^{k-2/5})$$
If we assume in additional that $f$ is an eigenfunction of all Hecke operators $T_nf=λ_f(n)f$ and $a(1)=1$ then $$\lambda_f(n)=\frac{a(n)}{n^{(k-1)/2}}$$
By partial summation we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\le x}|\lambda_f(n)|^2 
& = \sum_{n\le x}\frac{|a(n)|^2}{n^{k-1}}\\
& = \frac{A(x)}{x^{k-1}}+(k-1)\int_1^x\frac{A(t)}{t^k}dt \\
& =\alpha.x+O(x^{3/5})+(k-1)\int_1^x(\alpha+O(t^{-2/5}))dt\\
&=c.x+O(x^{3/5})
\end{align}
where $c=\alpha.k$

Comment: @user1952009, Okay I will send to you the paper.

Comment: tks ${}{}{}{}{}$